# No text is pasted when text is longer than max length in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am trying to paste a longer text in a textfield, longer than the defined maximum length. However no text is pasted. Is this a default behavior in iOS?

Thanks

Comment: What "defined maximum length"?

Comment: I used the shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString function and set the max length of it to 32. However when I am trying to paste a text with length grater than 32, not text was pasted on the textfield

Comment: If you return `NO` from that method, it means "Don't change the text"

Comment: That explains it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @borrrden put it as answer.. then OP can accept it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior is (to quote the documentation):

> YES if the specified text range should be replaced; otherwise, NO to keep the old text.

So, as you can see, returning `NO` means that the text will not change.